# Implement Query in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to implement this query in xcode

```
Select * from people where age >40 and mariageState = false
```

I can retrive all records but could not narrow my search with the conditions of age and mariagestae

How can I use NSPredicate or NSFetchRequest to implement such query?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the same syntax

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"people")    
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "age > 40 AND mariageState == FALSE")
```

You can easily add sort descriptors

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true), 
                           NSSortDescriptor(key: "age", ascending: false)]
```

Comment: I was thinking of something completely different. My issue is solved. Thank you

Comment: How can i combine it with sortDescriptor? For example by firstName ascending and age descending.